# NPM Versions update major number on every breaking change?

Tags: node.js, npm, semantic-versioning

Let's say my npm package of 1.0.0 publicly exposes a function called `foo` for users to use among many other functions and features.

I then remove the `foo` function which will break for all the users who are using this function.

NPM says:

> Changes which break backwards compatibility: Major release, increment the first number, e.g. 2.0.0

I'm quite confused exactly what this means.
Should the major number be updated always if we break a change for users even if it's just a small change such as removing a function?

At the moment I update the major number whenever I possibly break a publicly exposed feature. I see npm packages with small major versions and thinking that I am incorrect in doing this as I am updating my own packages major number very fast.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each API change (e.g. removing endpoint, function from lib, or changing behavior of endpoint/function) which may impact clients should update MAJOR number. MINOR and PATCH tells client that library/API is stable for one MAJOR version.

> Given a version number MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH, increment the:
>
> - MAJOR version when you make incompatible API changes,
> - MINOR version when you add functionality in a backwards-compatible manner, and
> - PATCH version when you make backwards-compatible bug fixes.

You can read more at http://semver.org/